# how to bind endpoints?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

although there are many posts about the same issue I still haven't figured out how to solve the problem regarding endpoints.

In the solution there are several projects and after reading about similar problems I edited the app.config file of the StartUp Project the following way:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
...
<service name="LiveGames.Engine.LoginService">
        <endpoint address="" name="ILoginService" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="LiveGames.Entities.Interfaces.ILoginService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/LiveGames.Engine/LoginService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/LiveGames.Engine/LoginService/"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ILoginService" contract="LiveGames.Entities.Interfaces.ILoginService"
          name="ILoginService" kind="" endpointConfiguration="">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I created the Proxy class with the following methods:

```
public ChannelFactory<T> GetFactory<T>(string serviceName, out T channel)
{
    ChannelFactory<T> factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(serviceName);
    channel = factory.CreateChannel();

    return factory;
}

public JSONUserLogin Login(string username, string password)
{

    JSONUserLogin retval = new JSONUserLogin();
    ILoginService sec = null;

    ChannelFactory<ILoginService> factory = null;

    try
    {
        using (factory = GetFactory<ILoginService>("ILoginService", out sec))
        {
            retval = sec.Login(username, password);
        }
        return retval;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new JSONUserLogin();

    }
    finally
    {
        if (sec != null)
            ((IChannel)sec).Close();

        if (factory != null)
            factory.Close();
    }

}
```

When `serviceName="ILoginService"` and the execution hits the line `ChannelFactory<T> factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(serviceName);`

it throws an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find endpoint element with name 'ILoginService' and contract 'LiveGames.Entities.Interfaces.ILoginService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong here and how to fix the problem?

Comment: You are connecting to `http` but using `wsHttpBinding` which is for secure connections. Is this deliberate?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Enabled tracing? Check if you can catch some exception there.